# Laravel How to keep login form data in the Request after clicking a link?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, http-post

I have this situation in the Laravel's login form where I check whether a user account is active or not. If the user is not active `('active' = false)` I log out the user (I don't let him log in) and show a message with a link saying *Resend activation link*, So this link takes to a controller that handles the resending by looking for the email of the form inside the request, but I am getting this error of email not found, since in the Request, the email is not being included!

Then the resulting query is:

`"select * from`users`where`email`is null"` because the email is not being kept inside the Request.

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

If I `dd($request)` just exactly in the login page, I do see the `email` property. But then why isn't it being included in the request when clicking on the *Resend* link????

**LoginController.php**

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        if(!$user->active){
            Auth::logout();

            dd($request->email); /*Here I do see the email*/

           /*But here comes the problem, the email is not being kept in the request. Why???????????*/
          return redirect('/login')->with('error','Please activate your account. <a href="'.route('auth.activate.resend').'"><strong>Resend</strong></a>');
        }
    }
```

**dd($request) after logging in and `active` = 0**

`+request: ParameterBag {#39 ▼
    #parameters: array:3 [▼
      "_token" => "o8t6GYwMmW6SfjfX732weghwejSBzOdWpcMf8HOL"
      "email" => "me@somewhere.com"
      "password" => "secreto"
    ]
  }`

At this moment, I show the **Resend** link and then

**dd($request) after clicking on the `resend` button**

`+request: ParameterBag {#46 ▼
    #parameters: []
  }`

I see that the parameters section is now empty :(

I have also tried, inside the LoginController.php, `$request->request->add(['email' => $user->email]);` but it doesn't work either.

Then how do I keep the email data in the Request so I can use it from a clicked link in another controller??? Is there any other workaround?

Comment: you can keep them in sessions or in cache ?

Comment: Yeah, I tried sessions and it's working now. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: you are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `withInput` method of `Request` like so:

```
return redirect('/login')
            ->with('error','Please activate your account. <a href="'.route('auth.activate.resend').'"><strong>Resend</strong></a>')
            ->withInput($request->except('password')); // This will not send password.
```

For more you can check :
https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#old-input